# Command line multitrack audio looper for Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, audio

Given a number of audio files, (say, *.wav), I'd like a command line way to mix these files as tracks with individual volumes, and define global loop points, so the audio mix loops seamlessly.

Could anyone suggest any alternatives?

Many thanks in advance,
Cheers!

---

In fact, a "command line looper" can almost be achieved with `melt` and the file below - the problem is that: the looping is not really seamless (there are audible clicks); I cannot see a way to mix more than two channels; and in spite of adding the `-audio-track | -hide-video` switch on the command line, a blank screen is still shown. (*some more on looping in `melt` here: [Re: [Mlt-devel] loop for producer](http://www.mail-archive.com/mlt-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02003.html)*)

This command must be used to call `melt` in "looping" mode:

```
melt eof=loop loop.mlt
```

... while the `loop.mlt` file (calling upon audio files `test.wav` and `test2.wav`) is this (it will be 70 frames long during loop playback in total):

```
<mlt>
  <producer id="producer0">
    <property name="aspect_ratio">0.000000</property>
    <property name="resource">test.wav</property>
    <property name="audio_index">0</property>
    <property name="video_index">-1</property>
    <property name="global_feed">1</property>
  </producer>
  <producer id="producer1">
    <property name="aspect_ratio">0.000000</property>
    <property name="resource">test2.wav</property>
    <property name="audio_index">0</property>
    <property name="video_index">-1</property>
    <property name="global_feed">1</property>
  </producer>
  <playlist id="playlist0">
    <entry producer="producer0" in="0" out="30"/>
    <blank length="10"/>
    <entry producer="producer0" in="0" out="30"/>
  </playlist>
  <playlist id="playlist1">
    <blank length="30"/>
    <entry producer="producer1" in="0" out="10"/>
  </playlist>
  <tractor id="tractor0" title="loop.mlt" global_feed="1" in="0" out="71">
    <multitrack id="multitrack0">
      <track producer="playlist0" hide="video"/>
      <track producer="playlist1" hide="video"/>
    </multitrack>
    <transition id="transition1" in="0" out="71">
      <property name="a_track">0</property>
      <property name="b_track">1</property>
      <property name="mlt_service">mix</property>
      <property name="start">0.5</property>
      <property name="end">0.5</property>
      <property name="combine">1</property>
      <property name="always_active">1</property>
    </transition>
  </tractor>
</mlt>
```

Comment: I wonder if ffmpeg doesn't reach the goals. Combining wavs and looping them almost certainly doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think I found a solution for a Linux command-line multitrack audio looper - and that is to use a [ChucK => Strongly-timed, On-the-fly Audio Programming Language](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/) script.

First of all, `ChucK` can be installed via `sudo apt-get install chuck` in Debian/Ubuntu. However, after you install, try to type `chuck` and then <kbd>TAB</kbd> in terminal; you should get something like:

```
$ chuck
chuck       chuck.alsa  chuck.oss
```

... that is to say - note that there are *three* `ChucK` executables; each for a separate Linux audio backend - and note that the default executable, `chuck`, actually refers to JACK (the other executables, obviously, refer to ALSA and OSS).

Since most typical users on Linux (also myself) do not actually have `jack` installed - running the `chuck` executable may cause dissapointment, as it won't result with sound (given that `jack` is not present on the system); see, for instance:

- [[chuck-users] chuck and jack fedora linux](https://lists.cs.princeton.edu/pipermail/chuck-users/2008-February/002668.html)
- [taw's blog: Using a DDR dance mat as a musical instrument](http://t-a-w.blogspot.com/2007/05/using-ddr-dance-mat-as-musical.html)

You may want to run `chuck --probe` and see what is reported for different backends - expect a complaint from `chuck` if JACK is not present and running, but `chuck.alsa` should pass:

```
$ chuck --probe
[chuck]: (via rtaudio): no devices found for compiled audio APIs!
[chuck]:
# .....
$ chuck.alsa --probe
[chuck]: found 4 device(s) ...
[chuck]: ------( chuck -- dac1 )---------------
[chuck]: device name = "hw:SB,0"
[chuck]: probe [success] ...
[chuck]: # output channels = 6
[chuck]: # input channels  = 2
[chuck]: # duplex Channels = 2
# .....
```

For most users, then, running `chuck.alsa` instead should do the trick - however, note that this will likely take up the audio device directly (doesn't look like `chuck` is aware of `pulseaudio`) - and then you will not be able to run other audio-generating programs (like `vlc`) in parallel, and have the sound mixed from both applications (the other application will basically stay silent).

But this being noted - we can now proceed with a `ChucK` script for looping.

One of the great things about `ChucK` is that basially we can define one script that handles the playback and looping of just one sound - and then call multiple instances of that script *in parallel* - which effectively creates a multitrack audio looper!

After some messing around with `ChucK` examples - see:

- [ChucK - [Examples By Category]](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/examples/)
- [The ChucK Tutorial](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/learn/tutorial.html)

... I managed to cook my own script - primarily based on examples: [sndbuf.ck](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/examples/basic/sndbuf.ck) and [valueat.ck](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/doc/examples/basic/valueat.ck) - which I've called [loopsndbuf.ck](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/loopsndbuf.ck):

```
// sound file
// initialize empty string variable for filename
"" => string filename;

// set a default filename to be loaded
"/path/to/freesound.org/100391__dobroide__20100627-creek.wav" => filename;

// if arguments are passed to the script,
// use the first argument as filename instead
if( me.args() ) me.arg(0) => filename;

0.5 => float myvolume;
if( me.args() ) if (me.arg(1) != "") Std.atof(me.arg(1)) => myvolume;

<<< "myvolume: " + myvolume >>>;

SndBuf buf;

filename => buf.read;
myvolume => buf.gain;
1.0 => buf.rate;


// time loop
Impulse i => dac;
while( true )
{
    int pos;

    repeat( buf.samples() )
    {
        buf.valueAt( pos ) => i.next;
        pos++;
        1::samp => now;
    }
}
```

(*see the online version for more comments*)

Having saved this script, we can now call it with `chuck` as interpreter:

```
chuck.alsa loopsndbuf.ck
```

... which will start loading the sound as in default settings, and looping it. Or, we can call the script with arguments - note that the character to separate arguments from a `chuck` script is colon (`:`):

```
chuck.alsa loopsndbuf.ck:/path/to/freesound.org/23222__erdie__thunderstorm2.wav:0.4
```

... or, - finally - we can call multiple instances of the `loopsndbuf.ck` script, which `chuck` will run in parallel. For this, I'd rather put everything in a bash script, let's call it `loopchuck.sh`:

```
set -x
PTH="/path/to/freesound.org"

chuck.alsa \
loopsndbuf.ck:$PTH/15528__ch0cchi__domestic-cat-purr.wav:1.0 \
loopsndbuf.ck:$PTH/100391__dobroide__20100627-creek.wav:0.05 \
loopsndbuf.ck:$PTH/23222__erdie__thunderstorm2.wav:0.4 \
loopsndbuf.ck:$PTH/2519__rhumphries__rbh-rain-01.wav:0.4 \
loopsndbuf.ck:$PTH/18766__reinsamba__chimney-fire.wav:0.4 \
loopsndbuf.ck:$PTH/53380__eric5335__meadow-ambience.wav:0.4
```

Running this script should basically load separate instances of the script, each with their own file and volume - `chuck` will then first load all audio into memory, spitting something like this to stdout:

```
$ ./loopchuck.sh
++ PTH=/path/to/freesound.org
++ chuck.alsa loopsndbuf.ck:/path/to ....
"myvolume: 1.0000" : (string)
"myvolume: 0.0500" : (string)
"myvolume: 0.4000" : (string)
"myvolume: 0.4000" : (string)
"myvolume: 0.4000" : (string)
"myvolume: 0.4000" : (string)
```

... and then, it will have all the scripts start at the same time - and then it will loop all the sounds individually at sample accuracy, according to their file length - wrapping the loop for each file, when it concludes, separately. In other words, the phases of the loops are independent (*similar to how the GUI program [terminatorX](http://terminatorx.org/) treats loops by default*) - and that is *exactly* what I was looking for `:)` !! Note that you may have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> twice to fully stop the `loopchuck.sh` script. (*and yes, the audio samples used are from [Freesound.org](http://www.freesound.org/)*)

Note, however, that while `chuck` loads all these files in memory, it uses quite a bit of CPU reproducing and mixing these loops - and so expect to have drops in the audio, if the OS has to handle some heavy operations (like GUI, say in the case when scrolling a webpage in your browser). In order to avoid this, I guess a `jack` setup has to be used - but then one has to get involved with Linux real-time priorities and whatnot (which isn't necessarily a straightforward process).

Well, I guess I'm happy now - since this is all I wanted (*<s>I just wish I could mix this audio output with one from say `vlc` or youtube in `firefox`, though</s> - done, check other answer*) `:)`; hope it helps others, too,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but I was searching a chuck looper, so I'm writing one. Any help is welcome. https://github.com/rodolfoap/chucklooper 
The idea is to imitate the Boss RC-50 LoopStation. Not hard with chuck, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally managed to get Linux `chuck` and PulseAudio to work together - now moved to [Getting an ALSA program (ChucK) to work with Pulseaudio?](https://superuser.com/questions/537030/getting-an-alsa-program-chuck-to-work-with-pulseaudio/537032#537032) - else see [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/405910/command-line-multitrack-audio-looper-for-linux/421181#421181) here...