# Getting an ALSA program (ChucK) to work with Pulseaudio?

Tags: linux, alsa, pulse-audio

Moving a previous answer to this topic; formulated as a question, it would be:

I'm using [ChucK](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/), in particular `chuck.alsa`, to implement a [Command line multitrack audio looper for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/405910/command-line-multitrack-audio-looper-for-linux).

Unfortunately, [that solution](https://superuser.com/a/421181/39752) takes up the soundcard, and cannot mix its audio output with other applications (VLC, Firefox/Flash (youtube), ...), which otherwise use PulseAudio for the purpose.

How can one make an ALSA executable like `chuck` route its audio through PulseAudio, so it can mix its audio output with other applications?

Answer (score 3):

(*moved from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/405910/command-line-multitrack-audio-looper-for-linux/536671#536671)*):

Well, I finally managed to get Linux `chuck` and PulseAudio to work together  - so that I could run the `chuck` script from [that post's accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/421181/39752) together with, say, VLC or a Youtube Flash, and have their respective audio outputs automatically mixed... So, I'm going to document it here..

### Chuck versions

Note that the accepted answer was done on:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS \n \l
```

... for which the associated `chuck` version is:

```
$ chuck.alsa --version    
chuck version: 1.2.0.8 (dracula)
   exe target: linux (alsa)
   http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/
```

Note that the latest `chuck` [source version](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/release/) (as of time of writing) is 1.3.1.3. `chuck` will need to be changed in source and rebuilt, in order to get it working with PulseAudio.

There are some differences between `chuck` versions 1.2.0.8 and 1.3.1.3, one of which causes:

### Change of loop script for chuck 1.3.1.3

If we look at the `chuck` [VERSIONS](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/release/VERSIONS) file, we can notice the following:

> 1.3.1.1
>   ---
>   ...
>    - (fixed) Machine.add( ... ) on windows now supports both '\'
>              and '/' in aboslute paths (previously only '\').

The original call to `loopsndbuf.ck` is of a format:

```
chuck.alsa \
loopsndbuf.ck:/path/to/file1.wav:1.0 \
loopsndbuf.ck:/path/to/file2.wav:0.5 \ ...
```

... where the colon `:` was parsed as a delimiter for `chuck` script arguments; and the first argument in that list was the filename `chuck` script being called (in this case, `loopsndbuf.ck`).

With the above change in 1.3.1.3, the combination colon and slash `:/` now causes the engine to skip parsing - thus the entire `loopsndbuf.ck:/path/to/file1.wav` gets to be interpreted as a `chuck` script filename - which will, of course, cause the call to fail.

Thus, in principle we could simply insert any character between the `:` and the `/` in the script call - and then parse it away in the `chuck` script. Unfortunately, as of now, the `chuck` scripting engine doesn't seem to have facilities for general string parsing (see [[chuck-dev] charAt, substring for strings](https://lists.cs.princeton.edu/pipermail/chuck-dev/2012-March/000438.html)); however, it does have whitespace trimming (see `init_class_string` in [chuck_lang.cpp](https://github.com/alltom/chuck-cvs/blob/master/v2/chuck_lang.cpp)).

So, while we cannot use *any* character as separator - we can certainly use <kbd>SPACE</kbd> as separator - which then also forces us to quote the arguments in the script call. Thus, the call itself (in `loopchuck.sh`) needs to be changed to:

```
chuck.alsa \
loopsndbuf.ck:" /path/to/file1.wav":1.0 \
loopsndbuf.ck:" /path/to/file2.wav":0.5 \ ...
```

... and the `loopsndbuf.ck` script needs the `if( me.args()...` line to be changed to:

```
if( me.args() ) me.arg(0).trim() => filename;
```

The good thing is, though, that such a call works for both 1.2.0.8 and 1.3.1.3 versions of `chuck`.

### Building `chuck` from source

As mentioned, the latest source code release (as of now) of `chuck` [chuck-1.3.1.3.tgz](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/release/files/chuck-1.3.1.3.tgz); I built this again on the Ubuntu 10.04 machine.

Now, on this Ubuntu 10.04 I have enabled the [lucidbleed PPA](https://launchpad.net/~lucid-bleed/+archive/ppa); which offers latest versions of, say, `libogg-dev` from within `apt-get` - but for some reason, does not offer the corresponding version of `libvorbis-dev` - which is otherwise pulled by `libsndfile-dev` (which is a requirement for building `chuck`). Which is why matching `libvorbis-dev` has to be downloaded, and the installation of packages has to go in several steps, using both `dpkg -i` and `apt-get install` (see commands below).

Besides the `build-essential` tools, the packages I needed to install can be seen below (it could be that I have already had installed other necessities, so check [ChucK manual: ch004_installation: Linux building and dependencies: Compiling ChucK & miniAudicle on Ubuntu 9.10](http://en.flossmanuals.net/chuck/ch004_installation/)). Below are commands to build `chuck` for ALSA - since that is the executable which is relevant for eventual PulseAudio changes:

```
# dependencies
wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/lucid-bleed/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/libv/libvorbis/libvorbis-dev_1.3.1-1ubuntu1~ppa1~lucid1_i386.deb

sudo apt-get install bison flex libasound2-dev libogg-dev
sudo dpkg -i libvorbis-dev_1.3.1-1ubuntu1~ppa1~lucid1_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install libsndfile-dev

# source
wget http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/release/files/chuck-1.3.1.3.tgz
tar xzvf chuck-1.3.1.3.tgz
cd chuck-1.3.1.3/src
make linux-alsa

# can copy executable at end manually (if not using `make install`):
sudo cp chuck /usr/bin/chuck.alsa-1.3.1.3

# cleanup dev libraries
sudo apt-get remove --purge bison flex libasound2-dev libsndfile-dev libogg-dev     # also removes libvorbis-dev
#sudo dpkg -r libvorbis-dev      # no need; dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libvorbis-dev which isn't installed
```

#### Debug build

If you want to compile a debug build of `chuck` (so you can inspect it with `gdb`); simply edit `makefile.alsa` (in the `chuck-1.3.1.3/src` directory): comment the first line, and make a new one, where optimization switch `-O3` is replaced with debugging switch `-g`:

```
# CFLAGS+= -D__LINUX_ALSA__ -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -D__CK_SNDFILE_NATIVE__
CFLAGS+= -D__LINUX_ALSA__ -g -fno-strict-aliasing -D__CK_SNDFILE_NATIVE__
...
```

... then run `make clean` - and finally again `make linux-alsa`.

### Hack for `chuck` with PulseAudio under ALSA

First of all, it's nice to be reminded of the relationship between ALSA and PulseAudio - I like the note from [How do you use both Pulse Audio and Alsa? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147981/how-do-you-use-both-pulse-audio-and-alsa):

> There are four layers in this abridged explanation of the audio stack.
>
> 1. The hardware.
> 2. ALSA.
> 3. Pulseaudio
> 4. Applications.

Other relevant pages are [How do ALSA and PulseAudio relate? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/144648/how-do-alsa-and-pulseaudio-relate) or [Pulseaudio vs ALSA - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1794581) (see also [Pulseaudio-diagram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/00/Pulseaudio-diagram.svg/800px-Pulseaudio-diagram.svg.png)).

Second, there are two ways to access a hardware device from ALSA - one through the `hw:` interface, and another through the `plughw:` interface. Note that the `plughw:` interface adds functionality like auto sample rate conversion to devices - but doesn't by itself provide mixing of audio of different applications! For more, see the thread [linux.alsa.devel - Re: devices/subdevices, hw:/plughw:](http://osdir.com/ml/linux.alsa.devel/2002-09/msg00382.html). Also note that in the `chuck` source ([src/RtAudio/RtAudio.cpp](https://github.com/alltom/chuck-cvs/blob/master/v1/rtaudio.cpp)) we can find:

> // I'm not using the "plug" interface ... too much inconsistent behavior.

Third - on top of that, there are two ways of addressing ALSA structures - seen in the [difference of output](https://superuser.com/questions/53957/what-do-alsa-devices-like-hw0-0-mean-how-do-i-figure-out-which-to-use/53977#53977) from ALSA's `aplay -l` and `aplay -L`:

- `aplay -l`: [the list of hardware devices](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8143)

  - lists card/device/subdevice
  - -l, --list-devices: function `device_list`
  - [function](http://alsa-utils.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.22-1/aplay_8c-source.html) loops through `snd_card_next`
- `aplay -L`: [the list of output devices - that may be hardware devices, or any of the many plugins of alsa (pulseaudio plugin, dmix, whatever)](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8143)

  - lists outputs (addressable by name)
  - -L, --list-pcms: function `pcm_list`
  - [1.0.22 aplay.c](http://alsa-utils.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.22-1/aplay_8c-source.html) function loops through `snd_device_name_hint`; while [1.0.8 aplay.c](http://alsa-utils.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.8-4/aplay_8c-source.html) function uses `snd_config_search`

Notably, `pulse` as an output name, which specifies usage of PulseAudio, appears only in `aplay -L`. The problem is that `chuck` essentially works with ALSA hardware devices (cards), given that `chuck.alsa --probe` essentially returns the same list as `aplay -l`. As such, `chuck` doesn't have a direct possibility to access the `pulse` device - and the only possible way is to replace the access to a device named `hw:X,Y` in the `chuck` code, with a device named `pulse`.

In the `chuck` code, only a single file needs to be changed, `RtAudio.cpp`; below is the diff:

```
--- ./RtAudio/RtAudio.cpp.orig  2013-01-14 16:18:18.113645910 +0100
+++ ./RtAudio/RtAudio.cpp   2013-01-14 18:46:15.289672175 +0100
@@ -5657,7 +5699,8 @@
         if ( result < 0 ) break;
         if ( subdevice < 0 ) break;
         if ( nDevices == device ) {
-          sprintf( name, "hw:%d,%d", card, subdevice );
+          //~ sprintf( name, "hw:%d,%d", card, subdevice );
+          sprintf( name, "pulse");
           snd_ctl_close( chandle );
           goto foundDevice;
         }
@@ -5696,6 +5739,7 @@

   snd_pcm_t *phandle;
   int openMode = SND_PCM_ASYNC;
+  printf( "pcm name %s\n", name);
   result = snd_pcm_open( &phandle, name, stream, openMode );
   if ( result < 0 ) {
     if ( mode == OUTPUT )
```

Note that with this hack, `chuck.alsa` gets fully routed through PulseAudio, and settings of devices via `--dacN` would not be honored. However, it will also cause `chuck`, when running, to appear in `gnome-volume-control`:

[image: gnome-volume-control.png]

... as well as in `pavucontrol`.

Note that in this mode, the `chuck` process  may be slightly more sensitive to GUI events - as in, having slight drops in audio upon GUI intensive events like scrolling a Firefox window - but in general, the PulseAudio mode works as well (and uses as much CPU) as the direct ALSA mode. (On this PC, I'm fine with `chuck` just playing loops like that - however, if performance is important for you, you're probably better off trying a JACK route.)

#### Previous PulseAudio redirection attempts

Before finding the above hack, I tried several things to "redirect" ALSA audio to PulseAudio; needless to say, for the reasons above, it was impossible to achieve mixing with other application audio. There is, however, one method that can do that - with `aoss` routing the audio from `alsa.oss`; unfortunately it suffers from severe audio drops.

Besides using [/etc/asound.conf to redirect ALSA to PulseAudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#PulseAudio_through_JACK_the_new_new_way), below are other things I've tried, that (generally) failed to achieve proper mixing with application audio (just the first relevant line of the `loopchuck.sh` script):

```
# via https://askubuntu.com/questions/8425/how-to-temporarily-disable-pulseaudio
# cannot mix, may need `pulseaudio --kill` to stop suspension
pasuspender -- chuck.alsa \
...

# stutters at first, but plays continuously
chuck.oss \
...

# via [How come aoss is better than padsp? - Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1259514)

# stutters a lot - but mixes audio!
padsp chuck.oss \
...

# stutters very little (upon gui updates though) - and mixes!
sudo apt-get install alsa-oss
aoss chuck.oss \
...

# via http://razor.occams.info/blog/2009/02/11/pulseaudio-sound-forwarding-across-a-network/
# plays OK, no mixing
ALSA_PCM_NAME=pulse chuck.alsa \
...
```

### A simple Python/Tkinter GUI

On the PC where I'm using the `loopchuck.sh` I don't have a keyboard, so I pretty much wanted a simple GUI just to start and stop the process (and thereby the audio loop). So I put together a little Python script, [tkGui_ShellScriptRunner.py](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/tkGui_ShellScriptRunner.py), which you can throw in the same directory as `loopchuck.sh` - just enable the right `scriptcall = ...` line - and after `chmod +x`-ing the script, you can raise this GUI by double-clicking its icon:

[image: tkGui]

... and you can run and stop the script, via the corresponding buttons.